# Last GTID on replica matches source but data is not there

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, binlog, proxysql

We have a following set up:

- Multi A-Z source RDS instance (MySQL 8.0.32)
- Single #1 A-Z replica RDS instance (MySQL 8.0.32)
- Single #2 A-Z replica RDS instance (MySQL 8.0.32)
- ProxySQL (2.5.2)
- Binlog reader (2.1.5) attached to every instance above

Not an ideal solution (binlog reader + rds instances) but it worked quite well in terms of consistent reads for a fairly long time. Suddenly, we started encountering a rather weird issue where sometimes ProxySQL will direct a select query to a read replica right after an insert one, (since last GTID matches) but no rows are returned. After some delay, data does appear on replica.
Here are some relevant query logs from ProxySQL

`` {"client":"10.1.2.140:58194","digest":"0x263BD85E3E37AC2B","duration_us":7502,"endtime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.055585","endtime_timestamp_us":1686097172055585,"event":"COM_QUERY","hostgroup_id":10,"last_gtid":"995c5610-45cc-11eb-9176-127d61671803:40897807","last_insert_id":412696,"query":"INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mime_type`, `guid`) VALUES (4, '2023-06-06 20:19:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', 'Auto Draft', '', 'auto-draft', 'post', 'closed', 'closed', '','', '', '', '2023-06-06 20:19:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '', '')","rows_affected":1,"rows_sent":0,"schemaname":"dbdev","server":"proxysql-dev-db-rds-binlog-reader-main:3306","starttime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.048083","starttime_timestamp_us":1686097172048083,"thread_id":362,"username":"wp-user-dev"} {"client":"10.1.2.140:58194","digest":"0x923F6A7DFE9A25FC","duration_us":494,"endtime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.056195","endtime_timestamp_us":1686097172056195,"event":"COM_QUERY","hostgroup_id":20,"last_gtid":"995c5610-45cc-11eb-9176-127d61671803:40897807","query":"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 412696 LIMIT 1","rows_sent":0,"schemaname":"dbdev","server":"proxysql-dev-db-rds-binlog-reader-replica-1:3306","starttime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.055701","starttime_timestamp_us":1686097172055701,"thread_id":362,"username":"wp-user-dev"} {"client":"10.1.2.140:58194","digest":"0x923F6A7DFE9A25FC","duration_us":447,"endtime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.056736","endtime_timestamp_us":1686097172056736,"event":"COM_QUERY","hostgroup_id":20,"last_gtid":"995c5610-45cc-11eb-9176-127d61671803:40897807","query":"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 412696 LIMIT 1","rows_sent":0,"schemaname":"dbdev","server":"proxysql-dev-db-rds-binlog-reader-replica-1:3306","starttime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.056289","starttime_timestamp_us":1686097172056289,"thread_id":362,"username":"wp-user-dev"} {"client":"10.1.2.140:58194","digest":"0x43D8874EB4077ECA","duration_us":361,"endtime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.057181","endtime_timestamp_us":1686097172057181,"event":"COM_QUERY","hostgroup_id":10,"last_gtid":"995c5610-45cc-11eb-9176-127d61671803:40897807","query":"UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `guid` = '' WHERE `ID` = 412696","rows_affected":0,"rows_sent":0,"schemaname":"dbdev","server":"proxysql-dev-db-rds-binlog-reader-main:3306","starttime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.056820","starttime_timestamp_us":1686097172056820,"thread_id":362,"username":"wp-user-dev"} {"client":"10.1.2.140:58194","digest":"0x923F6A7DFE9A25FC","duration_us":429,"endtime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.057685","endtime_timestamp_us":1686097172057685,"event":"COM_QUERY","hostgroup_id":20,"last_gtid":"995c5610-45cc-11eb-9176-127d61671803:40897807","query":"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 412696 LIMIT 1","rows_sent":0,"schemaname":"dbdev","server":"proxysql-dev-db-rds-binlog-reader-replica-1:3306","starttime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.057256","starttime_timestamp_us":1686097172057256,"thread_id":362,"username":"wp-user-dev"} {"client":"10.1.2.140:58194","digest":"0x923F6A7DFE9A25FC","duration_us":425,"endtime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.058186","endtime_timestamp_us":1686097172058186,"event":"COM_QUERY","hostgroup_id":20,"last_gtid":"995c5610-45cc-11eb-9176-127d61671803:40897807","query":"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 412696 LIMIT 1","rows_sent":0,"schemaname":"dbdev","server":"proxysql-dev-db-rds-binlog-reader-replica-1:3306","starttime":"2023-06-07 00:19:32.057761","starttime_timestamp_us":1686097172057761,"thread_id":362,"username":"wp-user-dev"} ``

We followed [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/configuring-proxysql-binlog-reader/) guide to set it up initially.

Who's likely culprit here?
How can it be solved?
Why would it start happening suddenly?